# Layer list containing circle with outer stroke

Tags: android, android-drawable, xml-drawable, layer-list

I would like to create the following background with a `layer-list`:

[image]

So basically a circle which has an outer stroke border.
I created the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#fff"/>
            <size
                android:width="10dp"
                android:height="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">

            <stroke android:color="#ff" android:width="2dp"/>
            <size
                android:width="25dp"
                android:height="25dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

But this shows only one solid oval. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This Change Color as per your requirement

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:width="60dp"
        android:height="60dp"
        android:top="15dp"
        android:right="15dp"
        android:bottom="15dp"
        android:left="15dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:width="8dp"
                android:color="#ffffff"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is not exactly what i want! There should be a transparent gap between the solid circle and the border, as seen on the image.

Comment: @WonderCsabo Check my edited ans it is exactly what u want

Answer (score 1):

**Try this .xml File**

**Tried to edit also you want to Exact**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
    android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
    android:topRightRadius="20dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
    />
<solid
    android:color="#"
    />
<padding
    android:left="0dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:bottom="0dp"
    />
<size
    android:width="100dp"
    android:height="100dp"
    />
<stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#33779C"
    />
    android:shape="oval">>
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <size android:height="25dp"
        android:width="25dp"/>
</shape>
```

**The Result shape Like This...**

[image]